# HTML5 video background not working

Tags: html, video, html5-video, dreamweaver

Recently I started a college project where I would have a video as a background on my HTML5 index page. I had it working perfectly with a stock video but when I made my own video and converted it to .mp4, .ogv and .webm all I get now is the blank black screen. I see no fault in the code:

```
<video id="video_background" preload="auto" autoplay="true" loop="loop" muted volume="0">
        <source src="backgroundvideo.webm" type="video/webm"/>
        <source src="backgroundvideo.ogv" type="video/ogg ogv"; codecs="theora, vorbis"/>
        <source src="backgroundvideo.mp4" type="video/mp4"/>
        Video not supported
</video>
```

Could it be the movie converter I used? I used Miro Video Convertor.

Comment: If you rename the old video and replace the new one with it, does it work? Could you provide a link to the video files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provided the videos are stored in the same directory as the HTML, and you have the filenames correct, this should be fine. If you've tried it in several different browsers (I assume you have) then, yes, it's probably the video encoding.

Comment: I made the mistake of not placing the video's in the right folder and therefore they weren't loading. That's what happens when you stare at a project for too long